# Store results of inequality

Tags: equation-solving, list-manipulation

I eveluated some values using `Reduce` commend and I store them in a `Table`

```
t = Table[
  N[Reduce[ 1/(1 + f) <= p[[i]] <= 1 + f , f], 100], {i, 1, n}]
```

Elements of a table looks like: `{f>= 99.000000000000000000000000000000000, f>=49.00000000000000000000000000000000...}`

Now I want to plot this values for an integer domain. So I wanted to use ListPlot, but to use it I have to have a table which looks like: `{99.00000000000000000000000000000, 49.000000000000000000 ...}`

How can I transform the first table to the second, which includes only values?

Comment: Try evaluating `t[[All,2]]` or `f/.t`

Comment: I tried the second one earlier, but it wasn't working. But the first one t[[All,2]] works great! Thank you!

Comment: Please check the documentation for [Rule](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Rule.html).